# Rails 4 configuration and erb in scss for conditional cloudfront paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, config, erb

I am trying to add dynamic cloudfront asset full paths into my scss.  The path changes based on the evironment (staging, etc)

mystyle.scss

```
.some-image   {background-image: url(asset_path("#{Rails.configuration.adjusted_s3_cloudfront_path}landing/this-image.jpg"))}
```

or mystyle.scss

```
.some-image  {background-image: url(Rails.configuration.adjusted_s3_cloudfront_path('/landing/this-image.jpg'))}
```

or mystyle.scss.erb

```
.some-image  {background-image: url(<% Rails.configuration.adjusted_s3_cloudfront_path %>"/landing/this-image.jpg")}
```

development.rb

```
 config.adjusted_s3_cloudfront_path = "https://somecloufrontnumber.cloudfront.net"
```

production.rb

```
config.adjusted_s3_cloudfront_path = "https://#{ENV['S3_CLOUDFRONT_URL']}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you remove `config.adjusted_s3_cloudfront_path = "https://#{ENV['S3_CLOUDFRONT_URL']}"` in favor of declaring a helper in `app/controllers/application.rb`?

---

```
.some-image {
  background-image: url(<%= cloudfront_path('landing/this-image.jpg') %>)
}
```

app/controller/application.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def cloudfront_path(asset_uri)
    return ENV['S3_CLOUDFRONT_URL'] + 'asset_url'
  end
end
```